# .HTACCESS Apache Mod_Rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried to manage my website's requests from `http://example.com/index.php/register` to `http://example.com/register`

But it always shows no input file specified.

Now all i want to do is to remove the `/index.php` and rewrite the requests.
here is my `.HTACCESS` file i have tried multiple things but no luck.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Just let me know where the issue is.

Comment: Does it work if you change the last line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`?

Comment: Just remove ***RewriteBase /***. It will work.

Comment: also, name the file `.htacces`, not `.HTACCESS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to write `RewriteBase /`

Use below htaccess.

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
# add / before index.php
```

Hope it will work :-)

Comment: No luck after this all the request are redirected to the main index.php and nothing is changed .

Comment: Try without the question mark `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] `

Comment: @DusanBajic: Thanks for the point. By mistake it was there. :-)

Comment: @DusanBajic even after that no luck no input file specified

Comment: Does the page open if you enter `http://example.com/index.php/register` in browser address bar?

Comment: @DusanBajic yes the page opens but i want the exact page to be opened when i go to www.example.com/register , but it always shows no input file suggested . P.S im using godaddy shared hosting and it has many other domain in the home directory in my case quepos.fishing folder has the htaccess and script installed.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some reasons for not working this code

First - Allow override in apache config, You should know where is your apache config, usually it is in the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from All
</Directory>
```

Second - mod_rewrite is not enable, so you should enter this command for enabling that.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Third - If still your rewrite mode doesn't work, or you don't have an access to change the config of the server
you can see your register page like this:
http://quepos.fishing/index.php/register

Comment: well thanks for the reply i forgot to menton im using goddady hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Okay can we swap the situation what if i want to reroute all requests 
www.example.com/register to www.example.com/index.php/register